# How to indent <li> right

Tags: html, css

In my ordered list, I need the text to be indented around 40-50px. I tried using the following:

```
.shift{
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

<ol>
<li class="shift">
```

**First tried the margin**, then padding. Nothing works. What to do? Thanks

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/dydvjcmv/). How does the rest of your HTML look?

Comment: You want all lines of text in the `<li>` to be indented, or just the first line?

Comment: You should post all of your css, if you're using any more.

Comment: I want the full text be indented. Actually its a full theme, Enfold from TF. I put it in the Quick CSS. not working

Comment: Here is the stylesheet for lists:

Comment: ul, ol { margin-bottom: 20px;  }
 ul { list-style: none outside; margin-left: 0px;}
 ol { list-style: decimal; margin-left: 0px; }
 ol, ul.square, ul.circle, ul.disc { }
 ul.square { list-style: square outside; }
 ul.circle { list-style: circle outside; }
 ul.disc, .entry-content-wrapper ul { list-style: disc outside; }
 ul ul, ul ol,
 ol ol, ol ul { margin: 4px 0 5px 0px;  }
 ul ul li, ul ol li,
 ol ol li, ol ul li { margin-bottom: 6px; }

Comment: .entry-content-wrapper li {  margin-left: 1em; padding:3px 0;}
 .entry-content-wrapper div li { text-indent: 0; }
 .entry-content-wrapper .borderlist>li:first-child {  border-top:1px solid; }
 .entry-content-wrapper .borderlist>li { border-bottom:1px solid; padding: 5px 0; list-style-position: outside; margin:0;}

Answer (score 0):

[Usually](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) there is a padding or margin set on ol/ul to offset items, so this

```
ol { padding:0; margin:0; }
ol > li{ margin-left: 40px; }
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: Are you sure, [it doesn't really seem to do anything](http://jsfiddle.net/dydvjcmv/1/)?

Comment: That quite different than your answer. That isn't anything that's different from the code given in the question (margin-wise). We don't have enough information to tell what exactly is going wrong with the users code. Other than guessing.

Comment: NO. I want text after the number be indented. Your example shifts the entire thing.

Comment: Ah, finally we are coming somewhere... You want to style ::marker pseudo-element ( http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-lists/#selectordef-marker ). But I don't think it has landed into mainstream browsers yet. As for now `::before` and counter is the only option I think. See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

Comment: How to add an image of what I want to create?

Answer (score 0):

Use css text-indent, which can not be applied for inline elements, so you can put your text inside some div or p and then use text-indent for inner block element

for example

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p style="text-indent: 10px;">text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works only, partially. I am using the content as <ol><li>Text heading, <return>description text</li>. After your suggestion I did use as <ol><li><p style="text-indent: 10px;">heading <return key>description</p></li> but only heading gets indented

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your HTML resembles the following:

```
<div class="entry-content-wrapper">
  <div>
  <ol>
    <li>Test One</li>
    <li>Test Two</li>
    <li>Test Three</li>
  </ol>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I went through the CSS you provided and found two statements such that one and/or both of them are likely creating conflicts for the browser:

```
.entry-content-wrapper li { margin-left: 1em; padding:3px 0;}

.entry-content-wrapper div li { 
    text-indent: 0px; 
}
```

I deleted the preceding CSS  but used all the rest you provided, and added the following code:

```
ul, ol { margin-bottom: 20px; } ul { list-style: none outside; margin-left: 0px;} ol { list-style: decimal; margin-left: 0px; } ol, ul.square, ul.circle, ul.disc { } ul.square { list-style: square outside; } ul.circle { list-style: circle outside; } ul.disc, .entry-content-wrapper ul { list-style: disc outside; } ul ul, ul ol, ol ol, ol ul { margin: 4px 0 5px 0px; } ul ul li, ul ol li, ol ol li, ol ul li { margin-bottom: 6px; }

.entry-content-wrapper .borderlist>li:first-child { border-top:1px solid; } .entry-content-wrapper .borderlist>li { border-bottom:1px solid; padding: 5px 0; list-style-position: outside; margin:0;}

.entry-content-wrapper li { 
    margin-left: 40px; 
    padding:0 30px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
ol {
    counter-reset:li; /* Initiate a counter */
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;

}
ol > li{
    list-style:none;
}
ol > li::before {
    content: "(" counter( li ) ")"; /* Use the counter as content */
   counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
    padding-right:30px;
    list-style:outside;
}
li {
 width:300px;   
 padding-right:30px;
 text-indent: -50px;

}
```

Live Demo **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qqdcraw/11/)**

The result basically does what you'll have an easier time achieving once the pseudo-element marker becomes available in the major browsers.

Comment: I put that div div ol li in custom.css and <div class ... in the post. Still not working

Comment: I've revised the solution.  Please see if the above works for you now.